# How to subclass multiple controls using a single ATL window object

Tags: windows, winapi, subclass, atl

Let's say you've created a subclass for a control (perhaps as a `CContainedWindow`, or as just a `CWindowImpl`-derived class), and you've got a bunch of identical controls within a dialog that you'd like to subclass accordingly.

Is there an elegant way to subclass all of those identical dialog controls using a single instance of your ATL window class? If not, is there some other ATL class or function that would fit this purpose?  Or is it necessary to create a separate class instance for each control, and call the subclass method on it?  Thanks for any input.

Comment: in what problem create several instance of class  (instance per control) ?

Comment: Well it just seemed a little redundant.

Comment: [CContainedWindow::SubclassWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccontainedwindowt-class?view=msvc-160#subclasswindow) says, "The original window procedure is saved in m_pfnSuperWindowProc." If you subclassed five windows with a single CContainedWindow, then you would have to save five original window procedures, which is hard to fit into one variable. Each CContainedWindow needs to manage the state of the window that is being subclassed; there is no redundancy. Each is doing a separate job.